# Number of possible combinations of positive integer polynomial entries with restrictions.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, combinations

This question might be stupid to someone being an expert in this field. But I was not able to find a satisfying answer in the textbooks I have studied so far. My question is: how many possible different solutions are there to the following inequality:

$\sum_{i=1}^{m} \log_2(a_i)n_i \leq \frac{\ln(w)}{ln(2)}$

where $a_i$ is an integer sequence which is given, $w$ is a choosen integer and there for given too, if $n_i$ are the free-variables with a positive integere value? Or maybe better: How many combinations for $n_i$ are there with given $a_i, w$ such that the inequality holds true? I hope this is understandable but I have myself some issues with properly stating the question. So if someone even just is able to reformulate the question a bit more understandable this might help too for others to partially or fully answer it.

Edit: We have some restrictions to $a_i$ which might simplify the task a bit. First $a_1=1$ and all other $a_i>1$. Also none of the $a_i$ takes a positive integere value. In fact they are all irrational.

Comment: There are $2m + 1$ variables in your question.  Some of these are the input (you are given these numbers, and the answer should depend on them); some are the free variables whose solutions you are counting.  Can you clearly state which are which?  (For example, in the question "how many positive-integer solutions of $a + b = n$ are there in terms of $n$?", $n$ is the input and $a$ and $b$ are the free variables.)  [P.S. there is no randomness in this question.]

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry for the bad formulation of the question. All $a_i$ and $w$ are given and there for are the input variables. The "free-variables" then are all $n_i$.  Hope this ansers your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trough some further research and investigation I found the solution in a paper written by Rahim Mahmoudvand, Hossein Hassani, Abbas Farzaneh and Gareth Howell in the year 2010 (I will give citation further down in the answer).

As it seems my question can be solved via using generating functions and viewing the limit-case of our inequality above, which is the case for which the LHS actually equals $\frac{\ln(w)}{\ln(2)}$. In this case our equation is a linear diophantine equation (LDE). The procedure to find the integer solutions to this is given in the paper as well as how to repeat the procedure to get the number of integer solutions to the inequality not just the equality.

citation of the paper (in plain .txt format):

Mahmoudvand, Rahim & Hossein, Hassani & Abbas, Farzaneh & Gareth, Howell. (2010). The Exact Number of Nonnegative Integer Solutions for a Linear Diophantine Inequality. IAENG International Journal of Applied Mathematics. 40.